# Passing data between widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

How do you retrieve the data from the ChoiceChip widget and pass it to another widget when a button is pressed.

Here is my ChoiceChip

```
class ChoiceChipWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> reportList;

  ChoiceChipWidget(this.reportList);

  @override
  _ChoiceChipWidgetState createState() => new _ChoiceChipWidgetState();
}

class _ChoiceChipWidgetState extends State<ChoiceChipWidget> {
  String selectedChoice = "";

  _buildChoiceList() {
    List<Widget> choices = List();
    widget.reportList.forEach((item) {
      choices.add(Container(
        child: ChoiceChip(
          label: Text(item),
          selected: selectedChoice == item,
          onSelected: (selected) {
            setState(() {
              selectedChoice = item;
            });
          },
        ),
      ));
    });
    return choices;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      children: _buildChoiceList(),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to pass it in this widget when the button is pressed.

```
class AddCashForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddCashFormState createState() => _AddCashFormState();
}

class _AddCashFormState extends State<AddCashForm> {
  List<String> chipList = [
    "weekly",
    "bi-weekly",
    "monthly",
    "once",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new COHAppBar().getAppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              ChoiceChipWidget(chipList),
            ],
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Update Cash Flow"),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),

          //Text('${widget.selectedChoice ?? "File is empty"}'), Data goes here
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

.....
Do I need to add a constructor so I can pass the data when the botton is pressed? How can I pass data between widget like these

Comment: You want to pass data to other page but not calling that page?

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e could help to you. I'm offering callback methods in your situation

Comment: the easiest way is using constructor injection as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a callback function like this:

```
class ChoiceChipWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> reportList;
  final Function(String item) onItemSelected;

  ChoiceChipWidget(this.reportList, this.onItemSelected);

  @override
  _ChoiceChipWidgetState createState() => new _ChoiceChipWidgetState();
}
```

And when the item is selected, call the function like this:

```
onSelected: (selected) {
  setState(() {
    selectedChoice = item;
    widget.onChoiceSelected(item);
  });
}
```

Then when you create the widget, you can do this:

```
ChoiceChipWidget(chipList, (item) {
  print('Item selected: $item');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below line in RaisedButton on Pressed Event:-

```
final Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChoiceChipWidget(true));
Navigator.push(mContext, route);
```